# Dockerfile not able to build on Ubuntu 14.04 but does fine on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, docker, capybara-webkit

I have the following Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    python-pip \
    python-dev \
    python-lxml \
    build-essential \
    qt5-default \
    libqt5webkit5-dev \
    xvfb \
    git

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install \
    lxml \
    xvfbwrapper \
    flask \
    bs4 \
    dryscrape

# copy all files to /app
COPY . /app

# change working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# expose port
EXPOSE 5000

# run python
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

# run app
CMD ["myapp.py"]
```

`myapp.py` is a simple `flask` project which also involves some scraping using `dryscrape`. I can successfully build and run `myapp` from these on my Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 machines.
On my DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following error and the build doesn't get completed -

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dUcM4q/webkit-server/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-k2iocl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dUcM4q/webkit-server/
```

Also, it says -
No such file or directory src/webkit_server
even when I try to install it without docker. The issue could possibly be with webkit-server but how come docker doesn't manage to run it consistently on different systems?

Its not as if there's a problem with docker because I'm successfully running several test projects in golang, node.js, etc. on the same server using Docker.

I don't understand the issue or the reason why it appears because the same `Dockerfile` builds fine on other systems!

Comment: this is not your problem, but you should group all your `RUN apt-get install` commands, among other things, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: @user2915097 ohh yes definitely will do that once things are okay and we are ready to deploy but this issue is preventing me!

Comment: @user2915097 I've formatted the dockerfile correctly now! Many thanks for your suggestion but it still fails to build on a specific system like before.

Comment: so it seems webkit (or something related) needs some more info to be built correctly with Ubuntu 14.04, unlike Ubuntu 16.04. You should try, outside of Docker, running your project on a bar Ubuntu 14.04, and check what you need to install, to have it running correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was with a library - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788282

For some reason, this particular library which is involved in one of the dependencies of the build, doesn't go well on a 64-bit linux.
Either its 32-bit version has to be explicitly installed or a 32-bit base image must be used.

For simplicity, change the first line of the `Dockerfile` to -

```
FROM 32bit/ubuntu:16.04
```